# console output halts on scanf() method in C++

Tags: c++, io, bluetooth, serial-port, scanf

I am using the following method in a library to read data coming from a bluetooth device:

```
BTSerialPortBinding::Read(buffer, length)

Reads data from the bluetooth device, returns number of bytes read

buffer: pointer to buffer to hold received data
length: maximum namber of bytes to read
```

The method works well when I used `printf("%s", incomingData);`
to output the data to console.

However when I use `(scanf(incomingData, "6,%d,%d,%d\r\n", &x, &y, &z) == 3)` the console seems to stay open but doesn't output anything once it tries this line.

The data comes in continuously and is in this form as an example:

```
6, 211, 233, 232; 
6, 392, 29, 93;
6, 42, 82, 94;
```

I am looking to scan and extract the last three values and store them each in a int variable. Below is my code, I am using windows 10 running on Visual Studio 2015.

```
        char incomingData[256] = "";    
        int dataLength = 255;
        int readResult = 0;

        while (1)
        {
            readResult = bt->Read(incomingData, dataLength);
            incomingData[readResult] = 0;

            // this prints fine
            printf("%s", incomingData);

            int x, y, z;

            //stuck here 
            if (scanf(incomingData, "6,%d,%d,%d\r\n", &x, &y, &z) == 3) {

               printf("x:%d,y:%d,z:%d\n", x, y, z);
            }
            Sleep(500);
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want `sscanf()` if you intend to pass a string to parse, not `scanf()` which does a *blocking* read from the terminal, meaning that nothing else will happen until this completes - something it probably won't, as you weren't expecting to supply data on the terminal.

You may also need to put some thought into line terminators, in a platform-specific way.

Comment: `some thought into line terminators, in a platform-specific way.` what do you mean by this? If I want this to compile both on Mac and windows would the above code with sscanf() introduced be appropriate? The library I am using supports multiple platforms.

Comment: I mean that not only are there difference in line endings, you have to watch out for situations where lower layers try to "help" you by concealing those differences.  Now that I think about it more, it's also unclear that your bt->Read() call is necessarily going to give you back one line, no more, no less at a time, and if it does not that may drastically complicate your parsing, too.  Normally when you read a serial port, you get whatever has arrived, which may include the end of an old line and part of a new one...